# Не показывается PopUp menu

Tags: delphi, windows

Есть код

```
procedure TChartEx.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;
  if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) = 0)then
    Msg.Result := HTTRANSPARENT;
end;
```

Это обработчик сообщения графика `(TChart)` Если у меня не нажата левая кнопка мыши , то я пропускаю сообщение родителю. Если нажата ,то компонент делает свои дела, но вот контекстное меню не появляется. Как правильно обработать это сообщение чтобы контекстно меню появлялось?

Comment: здесь имелось в виду исправил текст вопроса. предыдущему читающему  не   понятна была формулировка. Вопрос открыт

Comment: Так контекстное меню вызывается при нажатии правой кнопки. Попробуйте, если нажата правая кнопка, возвращать HTCLIENT. Или я тоже не понимаю вопроса?